# How can I play a sequence of audio files based on the content of a textbox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, audio

I'm working on a railway announcement system and want to be able to take some information from a list e.g 'York, Darlington, Durham' and then play the relevant sound recordings once a button is pressed. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a Dictionary where the key represents your list item and the value represents the file location of the sound you wish to play once the button is pressed. You would then bind the Dictionary to your control where the control's displayed text is the Dictionary's Key and the control's value is the Dictionary's Value. That away you can just get the selected value of the control to play.

Here is an example using a ComboBox:

```
Private stations As Dictionary(Of String, String)
Sub New()
    stations = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    stations.Add("York, Darlington, Durham", "sound-a.mp3")
    'stations.Add("...", "...")

    With ComboBoxStations
        .DataSource = New BindingSource(stations, Nothing)
        .DisplayMember = "Key",
        .ValueMember = "Value"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub PlaySound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonPlaySound.Click
    If (ComboBoxStations.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing) Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(ComboBoxStations.SelectedValue.ToString(), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End If
End Sub
```